# Date Loop isn't working correctly

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

Hi I've created a while loop for dates. I want to increase the month my 1 every time. However it isn't working and instead it increments like this :
2009/06/01
2009/07/01
2009/09/01
2009/12/01
2010/04/01
2010/09/01

which isn't correct. I dont understand why it won't increment by 1 month. Any help would be much appreciated

```
 <?php

$startdate = "2009/06/01";
$enddate = "2009/12/31";

$start = strtotime($startdate);
$end = strtotime($enddate);

$f = 0;
$t = 6;
$d = 0;
$currentdate = $start;
while($f < $t )
{
       $cur_date = date('Y/m/d', $currentdate);


       $currentdate = strtotime($f . ' month', $currentdate);



          echo  $cur_date . "<br />";
        //echo  $f . "<br />";
        $f = $f + 1;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

It won't work because you're not adding 1 month each time.... you're adding 1 month in the first iteration, 2 in the second, 3 in the third, etc. because you're increasing the value of `$f` every iteration.

```
$begin = new DateTime('2009-06-01');
$end = new DateTime('2009-12-31');
$end = $end->modify('+1 day');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');

$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach($period as $dt) {
    var_dump($dt->format( "Y-m-d" ));
}
```

Comment: Hi, I still cannot get my head around how that is making the additive  increase by one at every iteration, isnt this the similar of `$f++` ?

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib - perhaps [this](https://3v4l.org/aP91E) will show you what OP's code is actually doing

Comment: Thanks for your time and being so considerate, still need some time to wrap my head around it :) also, does it mean that the while loop remembers the initial value of the variables incremented inside them?

Comment: Ohhh I see!! The `$f` is not the culprit, but the variable `$currentdate` is holding the stale values @ every loop, sorry my bad, I totally overlooked it.

Comment: Original values of variables are not "remembered" when a variable is changed, it simply takes the new value

Comment: Thanks for reply just wondering what I should change to get the correct output in my code.

Comment: @user3660857 - Change `$currentdate = strtotime($f . ' month', $currentdate);` to `$currentdate = strtotime('+1 month', $currentdate);`